# How to backup the chunk in Informix so that it can be restored after dropping it?

Tags: database, backup, informix, restore

I would like to drop a ***chunk*** of a ***dbspace*** in ***Informix 12.10 on Linux***. How to backup that chunk so that it can be recreated in future after dropping it?

I know that the chunk should be empty before dropping it.  If the chunk contains any tables, then is `onunload` and `onload` those tables into another dbspace the only way to backup those tables? If so please elaborate the syntax to `onunload` the table to another dbspace.

Comment: There's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) lurking here.  Why do you think you need to drop the chunk?  Did you place it in the wrong location, or on a disk that has no space left.  Are you simply trying to relocate the file backing the chunk?  In general, the best way to organize things is that the names specified to the server are symlinks that point to the currently correct location.  The advantage of this is that if you take the server offline, copy data from the chunk to a new location, and point the symlink to the new location, the server simply works on restart.

Comment: My regards sir , thanks for your precise subtle reply. your solution is a quick fix whilst I would like to explore conventional methods to drop a chunk provided by **_Informix_** like other databases, as I mentioned in the question if I want to drop a **_chunk_** that is not empty and has tables in it , is `onunload` and `onload` to another **_dbspace_** is the only way to backup those tables if so please explain `onunload` command as I am getting this error " Please mount tape and press Return to continue 
Error opening the tape device, Error No. = 13. " . I have set **TAPEDEV** parameter .